# Combining PHP Rtrim in MySql Query

Tags: php, mysql

I need to remove trailing dot from my domain name. I have example below. What is the correct way to use it in the query?

```
$tank5 = "SELECT url FROM `db`.`tank` WHERE url LIKE rtrim('%$string%', '.')"; // this don't work I just test it.
```

I know I can just do this `$string = rtrim($string, '.');` before the query but I was hoping I could run it on 1 line.

Is it actually possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concatenate your string, instead:

```
$tank5 = "SELECT url FROM `db`.`tank` WHERE url LIKE '%".rtrim($string, '.')."%'";
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't know you could actually concatenate php function in query. Well I learn new things everyday. That's solve it. Thanks again.

Comment: @sg552 Concatination of strings is always possible.

Answer (score 0):

RTRIM would remove trailing blanks.
You would need to use SUBSTRING.

```
$tank5 = "SELECT url FROM `db`.`tank` WHERE url LIKE CONCAT('%', SUBSTR($string, 1, LENGTH($string)-1), '%');";
```

If you would want to execute with SQL functions, but a much better way is to do as Repox said.